# How much can I claim in damages for a missed connection, on an EU airline flying through the EU?

Tags: legal, airlines, eu, compensation, missed-flights

On a flight from Asia to the US on British Airways recently, I missed the connection in London. The first flight was delayed because of mechanical reasons. London was chaotic and British Airways was quite rude and unresponsive but after a significant wait they agreed to put me up in a motel (quite seedy - particularly for someone travelling on business class). Since I could not access my checked-in bags I decided to pick up a set of undergarments from the airport. Am I allowed to charge these (which I think are very reasonable) to the airline. What am I allowed by law? (I have no clue what law applies).

Comment: If a national airliner puts a businessclass passenger in a motel after a missed connection, this passenger should yell the hell out of them.

Comment: My credit cards provide a benefit that covers this. Check your coverage because it will be much easier than dealing with an airline you're already irritated with.

Comment: Which hotel did BA put you up in? And why wouldn't they let you access your bags? (Flight Connections can normally request the bag be delivered even when it's checked through, if there's a good reason like an overnight delay)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[EU passenger rights apply](http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm). If the delay was not caused by "extraordinary circumstances", you may be entitled to some monetary compensation.

Comment: Do you know about USA? Is there an equivalent question for that?